# How can I selectively modify the lines in a file where the modifications depend on analyzing the select lines as a whole rather than individually

Tags: command-line, text-processing, vim

**TL;DR** I need to align the columns of the entries in fstab while ignoring the comments:

```
/dev/foo              /foo         ext4        defaults   0    2
# comment line 1
/dev/bar /bar ext4 defaults 0 2
# comment line 2
UUID=1234567890     /baz      ext4      defaults   0       2
```

should become

```
/dev/foo         /foo  ext4  defaults  0  2
# comment line 1
/dev/bar         /bar  ext4  defaults  0  2
# comment line 2
UUID=1234567890  /baz  ext4  defaults  0  2
```

in, ideally, one swooping command.

**`</tldr>`**

My `fstab` consists of a large block of documentation in comment lines ending with the field descriptions and finally the entries. There are comment lines interspersed in the entry section.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

# table entries begin ...
```

I'd like to align columns in the entry lines using the `column -t` command or equivalent but want to ignore the comments. If I don't ignore the comment lines, even they will be subjected to alignment. While editing the file in vim, I can visually select the lines from the first entry onward and run `'<,'>` `!grep '^[^\#]' | column -t` but grep will filter out the comment lines and as a result, they won't be present in the output, which replaces the selection in vim. I can't run the column command on each matching line individually because `column` doesn't work that way.

Is there a simple command that accomplishes this task? It need not be achievable in vim as I can simply delegate it to an external command from within.

Comment: I'm just curious as to why you want to do this, and normal tabbing isn't good enough

Comment: @ekaj What do you mean by normal tabbing? It's easier to read when all the columns are aligned properly.

Comment: Normal tabbing means take out spaces and "hit tab" until things work correctly. fstab isn't meant to be manually edited all the time, so who cares if it's a bit difficult to read? Your new lines will go at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

```
tr -s \[:blank:] \  </etc/fstab |       # squeeze all tabs/spaces to 1 space
sed 's/^#/ # # # # # #/'        |       # create 6 tiny comment fields
column -t                       |       # get columns
sed '/^\( *#\)\{6\}/{s//#/;s/  */ /g;}' # fix and squeeze spaces for comments
```